C# & EF Core : 2 databases mapped attribute is in first but not in second database
I have a little problem with my DbContext. I have two databases. Both have the same tables, but in the second database, there is an extension so some tables have more columns.
In my DbContext, I scaffolded the second database so I got all the columns.
When I start my application connected to the second database, all is fine, but connected to the first database, I got the error that attribute x,... doesn't exist.
Is there a way to connect to database 1 or 2 and say "Hey if the column X is not in the database, just don't map it?"
The NotMappedAttribute/Ignore is not the right way for me, I think. Because if I start my application with the second database, the extra columns are not in the result set.
Is the only way to create a second DbContext and the get the right one based on which database I connect to?
Thanks for your help and best regards
Philipp
Tried:

NotMappedAttribute/Ignore with Fluent API


Are the 2 databases supposed to be the same/have the same schema? Did you use the EF Core migrations on both of them to create/update them?

Yes have the same schema. We don't use the migration. I scaffolded the tables from the existing database. The Error occurs when i make a get Command to catch all records from the table.

"Yes have the same schema." Goes against the "Both have the same tables, but in the second database, there is an extension so some tables have more columns." There are differences so the have different schema! These differences are enough to trip up EF Core. Anything configured/mapped with EF Core must match the database. I don't think that there is any scope for anything that is mapped to not exist in the database without hitting errors like this. Either it exists in both databases or you don't use it!

I'm sorry. ok I understand. So best Solution is to create two DbContext and decide in programm start which to use. Thanks for your help :).

Personally I wouldn't but I guess you could do that. Why do you need the 2 different, but almost identical, databases anyway?

Because Customer A is a normal Customer with the standard database. Customer 2 has the Extension cash register so we need at some tables more columns to check the cash things. Because of our Software structure it is not possible to install at all customers the same database with the extension. Now we modernize our Software with c# and Blazor and at that point I stuck with this Problem :)

In that case I think 2 separate contexts are needed. Without knowing more about the project, it does sound like you have some potential issues with infrastructure. There should be no reason to have 2 almost identical databases beyond the usual multiple instances for dev/test/staging/production.

you are right. But thanks for the little Discussion. Helped me alot :)
